# How to reconstruct return type object in web api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

Given that I have the following web api method in my controller

```
    public HttpResponseMessage PostGrantAccess(GrantAccessRequest grantAccessRequest)
    {
        var deviceId = grantAccessRequest.DeviceId;

        var grantAccessResponse = new GrantAccessResponse()
            {
                Status = "OK"
            };
        var response = Request.CreateResponse<GrantAccessResponse>(HttpStatusCode.OK, grantAccessResponse);
        return response;
    }
```

Client calling code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:55208/");

    var request = new GrantAccessRequest { DeviceId = "bla" };
    var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/accesspanel", request).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var uri = response.Headers.Location;
    }
}
```

How do I get back `GrantAccessResponse` at the client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
response.Content.ReadAsAsync<GrantAccessResponse>()
```